# change div display style after function return

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, return

```
function getId($name)
{

$fburl = "$name";
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$fburl.'/?__a=1');
$regex = '/https:?\:\/\/[^\" ]+.cdninstagram.com/i';
if (preg_match($regex, $result, $matches))
{   
    sleep(5);
    return $matches[0]; 
}
}
```

Well this is the full function, Can I add to return some new commande to change display of div with id="wrong" from "none" to "block". I want this as a result too for the condition IF thanks.

Comment: You can't put code AFTER a return; return immediately ends the current function and doesn't execute any more of its code. If you want other effects inside the conditional, they have to be before the return.

Comment: I'm putting this code document.getElementById("wrong").style.display = "block"; before the return and it doesn't work neither...

Comment: And there's an element with ID "wrong" and you're sure this preg_match condition is being met?

Comment: Well yes there is an element with ID "wrong" in the index.php and i updated the full function, this code here is in the engine.php

Comment: This is PHP code... running in PHP... of course Javascript isn't going to work if you just put it in the middle of some PHP script...

Comment: Okey what i have to do to change div style display as a result for the condition?

Comment: Maybe by adding some commend to exec a script which change the display of the div ?

Comment: No... no no. The display of the DIV is controlled by the code that ultimately gets sent to the client. The PHP is running on the server, not the client. If you want the results of the PHP script to change the style, you need to echo some CSS or HTML styles onto the page from the PHP script that would apply the styles you want. PHP is only there to generate the resulting HTML, not to run anything on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this and it worked, just before the return:

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
document.getElementById('wrong').style.display ='block';</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can actually use `document.getElementById("wrong").style.display = "block";` which will override the currently assigned display value in the stylesheet.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i did it before and didn't work i type it just under that return right ?! can you write the full script please